# Contentful: Auto-generate title from fields

Tags: contentful, contentful-api

Contentful requires internal titles for each content entry to be determined in the related Content Type. This is for organizing content entries and making it easier to find them. These internal titles currently have to be filled out manually be the editors.

I am wondering if it is possible to **auto-generate a title based on fields that have been filled out**.

E.g. in the example I’ve added the editor would add a event location (“Eiffel tower”) and a date (“2021-10-25”) and the title would automatically genreate itself based on those two entries.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a feature request to me. Having the same issue, very annoying to be forced to always set a title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some time to adress the issue and created a simple Contentful app. It generates a title automatically from fields a user can choose:

https://github.com/nerdess/contentful-autotitle